# Using postfix without being able to set custom hostname

Tags: postfix, hostname, ubuntu-18.04

As the title suggests I am using a VPS that does not allow me to set a custom hostname. On every reboot the hostname is reset to their specification. Can I still run a postfix mail server on this machine?

Comment: Does the IP address change? What is the purpose of this postfix server. (These are important, as you may be able to run a postfix server but it might not make sense to do so)

Comment: The purpose is the run a complete mail server and the VPS has a static ip.

Comment: You can run postfix on this machine - but I expect you have an extremely steep learning curve and it may be worthwile  upskilling first. There are a lot of gotchas running a mail server, and I imagine you will find it very painful if you are at a level where setting a hostname on / immeduately after startup is not considered trivial.  Of bigger concern may be the practical requirement for forward and reverse DNS to match - but this is all just the tip of the iceburg.

Comment: I'm doing this to learn it, so it's not really productive telling me not to try it. Regardless, the problem that I seem to be facing isn't that I can't set the hostname, because that is indeed trivial, it's that my outside connection is blocked once I do it.

Comment: I never told you not to try it, I advised you need to upskill before you do. You have posted in a forum for *managing systems in a business environment*  -and the expectation here is you are have system administration competencies. At your level of knowledge your question is more appropriate on Superuser....

Comment: If you are having difficulty changing the host name, your question (on Superuser.com) should focus on that. There is nothing inherent in VM infrastructure tying the VM client to the server by host name. There are almost certainly changes you can make in your Ubuntu to allow you to change the hostname without causing you to loose connectivity. (As long as you really do have a static IP)